# Doxygen hide source files

Tags: c++, doxygen

I just started using Doxygen to generate documentation for my libraries and I found one minor glitch I can't get around.

In the tree view there's the file list and you can click on one of the files and then get the source code. I found a way to get rid of the file list but then I can't see the enums anymore.

Do you know any way to hide the source code from Doxygen?

Also, if you go to [bada API reference](http://dpimg.ospos.net/contents/docs/resources_0818/com.osp.apireference.help/FramesetMain.html?menu=MC01010304&mtb1=&mtb2=) website you will see in the tree view that there is no Class List or Class Members. There is just the Namespace List that contains the classes. Can I modify Doxygen to do the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm relatively new to doxygen, but disabling SHOW_FILES and VERBATIM_HEADERS options seems to get rid of the source code lists.

Comment: In my case I wanted anonymous namespace variables and enumerations to be available, which only happens if SHOW_FILES = YES. then, VERBATIM_HEADERS prevents source code from showing up. Is there a way to make Anonymous namespace variables accessible without showing files?